# How do I square a number using a for loop in php?

Tags: php, for-loop

My task, using php, is to create a random number, then make that number multiply itself. However i cannot use the multiply operator (*) and have been told to create a for loop instead however I'm having some troubles.

```
$startNum = rand(1,10);

for ($i = $startNum; $i <= 10; $i++)
{
  echo $i;
    }
```

This is what i have so far, however this is completely wrong and will only get a random number and count to 10 from it.
Any help would be very appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When squaring you are just multiplying a number by itself, another way to do this is through addition, add a number to itself x amount of times. So, with 4 squared, that is 4 * 4 or, 4 + 4 + 4 + 4.

Doing this in a for loop should be as simple as

```
$startNum = rand(1,10);
$endNum = 0;    

for ($i = 0; $i < $startNum; $i++)
{
  $endNum += $startNum;
}
echo $endNum;
```

Caveat: I don't program Php so forgive syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot, why does $endNum have to be a 0? Basically I'm confused as to why you use "$endNum += $startNum;", if you could give me a small explanation as to whats going here that would be very appreciated, thanks

Comment: $endNum starts at 0 because it's just a storage location for the final number, we are adding to it, so we don't want to start at anything other than nothing :) $endNum += $startNum is shorthand for $endNum = $endNum + $startNum. All it does is adds $startNum to $endNum. All that is happening is we are generating a random value, putting that random value into $startNum then adding that value to itself as many times as necessary, storing the result in $endNum. Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

`$startNum*$startNum` means that the loop should loop `$startNum` times and in each iteration add `$startNum`, i.e., the number itself

```
$s = 0;
for($i=1;$i<=$startNum;$i++){
    $s += $startNum;
}
echo $s;
```

Answer (score 1):

Still not using the multiplication operator :p

```
$n = mt_rand(1, 10);
echo array_sum(array_fill(0, $n, $n));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by simple addition(+) operator

**square means add that number into same number for same time.**

example : square of 2 means : 2+2;

square of 4 means : addition of 4 with 4 for 4 times : 4+4+4+4

so you can do like that

```
$startNum = rand(1,10);
$ans=0;
for ($i = 0 ;$i < $startNum; $i++)
{
  echo $ans+=$startNum;
}
```